# Using a variable using a variable value in EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

I want to access a variable of type `Map` from my model using EL. e.g.

```
${name} = "mycar"
${mycar} = "ferrari"
```

I tried `${${name}}` but it doesn't work. The expected value is "ferrari". What do you think is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Ah, in that case I'll delete my answer, the other two are accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. However, you can have a `Map` in your Java code that will be accessible using `${myMap[myValue]}`. So for example, in your JSP page you will have:

```
<c:set var="name" value="mycar"/>
<c:set var="myCar" value="${carsMap[name]}"/>
```

it's like you called `carsMap.get("mycar");` in Java...

Answer (score 1):

You can then loop around your `map`.

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${map}">
   ${entry.key}: ${entry.value}, 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @Bozho: Thanks for pointing that out. It was actually a copy/paste issue. ;)