# calling another variable using a variable value as parameter in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

the logic is somehow like this:

```
<c:set var="vehicle" value="car">
<c:set var="car" value="ferrari">
```

since the value of `${vehicle} = "car"` which is also the name of the variable with the value of "ferrari" i access it indirectly using `${'${vehicle}'}` but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me with this. thanks

Comment: this is weird, I would consider refactoring and taking a different approach.

Comment: what do you think would be the work around for this?

Comment: duplicate of [Using a variable using a variable value in EL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132286/using-a-variable-using-a-variable-value-in-el)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of things doesn't usually work in java (there's no `eval` statement). In this case however, the variables are bound to the request context, so I guess you could access it something like this (assuming the variables were assigned to request scope):

```
${requestScope[vehicle]}
```

But I can't verify that, because I have not written any JSP code for about 3 years.

Comment: He's however close. It only goes by default in `pageScope`.

Comment: @BalusC thanks, updated the text accordingly. But is the syntax correct?

Comment: Yes, see also the answer of Romaintaz in his duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported, and if it was `${'${vehicle}'}` wouldn't be the logical syntax for it.  (It would be more like `${${vehicle}}` ... hypothetically.)