# Setting JSP property with JSTL in a nested way?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, expression, jsp-tags

I have a JSP attribute named "form" set followingly

```
<c:set value="${fieldAttributeMap[rowId].buildForm}" var="form" />
```

This works. The attribute "form" contains a Java object, which will used for further evaluation and displaying later in the JSP. However, I would like to use it in a more general way without knowing what the form name is beforehand - it could be named e.g. "modelForm" instead of "buildForm". If we assume that I have stored the name of the variable in JSP attribute "formName"

```
<c:set value="buildForm" var="formName" />
```

how can I use this to set the JSP attribute "form" like in the first code example? Basically the expression would have to be evaluated twice, like in this imaginary, non-working example:

```
<c:set value="${fieldAttributeMap[rowId][${formName}]}" var="form" />
```

Only workarounds which come to my mind are either writing my own tag or using the antiquated Struts bean:define tag. But I'm hoping there is some better solution or workaround.

**Edit:** there was a suggestion that this question may be a duplicate of [calling another variable using a variable value as parameter in jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132865/calling-another-variable-using-a-variable-value-as-parameter-in-jstl) However, the solution offered there is not applicable here, as I need to substitute the name of the attribute as a property of another Java object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling another variable using a variable value as parameter in jstl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132865/calling-another-variable-using-a-variable-value-as-parameter-in-jstl)

Comment: I read the answer to the linked question and it seems to contain a possible solution to the problem. However, I have oversimplified the question to make it accessbile for the readers, so the linked question does not answer my real problem. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need `${fieldAttributeMap[rowId][formName]}`